# How to dynamically change the name of a stored procedure when using Spring SimpleJdbcCall

Tags: spring, spring-jdbc, spring-cache

I want to dynamically change the name of the called stored procedure from my application without having to deploy my application using SimpleJDBC.

I am using coherent caching to cache the active version of the stored procedure that is maintained in a control table. In the case when there is a functionality change without change to the input/output of the stored procedure, I deploy new version of the stored procedure and update the new name in the control table. After the TTL (time to livee) of the cache is expired and the cache is refreshed, the new name is made available to the application.

However my observation is even though the cache is refreshed the execute statement calls the older version of the stored procedure that was available during deployment, how can I change this

```
Map response = simpleJdbcCall.execute(new MapSqlParameterSource(map));
```

Any help with this is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Looks like something wrong with your design.

The `SimpleJdbcCall` is one-time-compiling object:

```
/**
 * Compile this JdbcCall using provided parameters and meta data plus other settings.
 * <p>This finalizes the configuration for this object and subsequent attempts to compile are
 * ignored. This will be implicitly called the first time an un-compiled call is executed.
 * @throws org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException if the object hasn't
 * been correctly initialized, for example if no DataSource has been provided
 */
public synchronized final void compile() throws InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException {
```

So, you can't change its internal state during runtime.

But I can suggest you the solution like a new cached instance for each new procedure name. For this purpose you can code some `@Cached` service which will return you a `SimpleJdbcCall` instance. Therefore, if you expire the cache, a new instance will be created for you and that is your responsibility to populate the actual procedure name to that fresh object.

P.S. And yes, there is nothing for [Spring Integration](http://projects.spring.io/spring-integration/), please, be careful choosing tags for the question.